# How to check if a path is for a view?

Tags: 8, views

I have a list of paths and I would like to identify which ones are associated to view routes.

Is there any Drupal 8 method I can use? Do I need to get all the view routes and then check which ones are associated to the paths I have?

Comment: What is a `view path`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the route name of the current page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202831/get-the-route-name-of-the-current-page)

Comment: Can you please check for the current route name and see if it contains any identifier like `*.view.*` or whatever you can use?

Comment: View page routes have route names formatted like: `view.VIEW_ID.DISPLAY_ID`

Comment: Convert into URL objects. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190036/how-do-i-convert-a-string-like-node-1-into-a-routematch-or-url-object

Comment: Thanks @4k4 I will try your solution as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to use the [router.route_provider](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.services.yml/service/router.route_provider/8.2.x) service. Specifically, you may want to use  [`RouteProvider::getRoutesByPattern()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RouteProvider.php/function/RouteProvider%3A%3AgetRoutesByPattern/8.2.x). See the following code, adapted from code shown in [joachim's comment](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2014-12-02/get-route-name-by-path-in-drupal-8#comment-12146001) in [Get route name by path in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2014-12-02/get-route-name-by-path-in-drupal-8).

```php
function getViewPaths(array $paths_to_check = []): array {
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProviderInterface $route_provider */
  $route_provider = \Drupal::service('router.route_provider');

  $view_paths = [];
  foreach ($paths_to_check as $path) {
    $path_route_collection = $route_provider->getRoutesByPattern($path);
    foreach ($path_route_collection->all() as $route_name => $route) {
      if (strpos($route_name, 'view.') === 0) {
        $view_paths[] = $path;
      }
    }
  }

  return $view_paths;
}

$my_view_paths = getViewPaths([
  '/about',
  '/some/other/path',
  '/one-more-path',
]);
```

Comment: Hi sonfd, thanks a lot for your solution. I think it should serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the list contains paths like /node/2, /user/1, or admin/content, and you need to get the route name for those paths handled by the Views module, you could use code similar to the following one.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Path\PathValidatorInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

function _view_routes(array $paths) {
  $view_routes = [];
  $path_validator = \Drupal::service('path.validator');

  foreach ($paths as $path) {
    $view_route = '';
    if ($url = $path_validator->getUrlIfValid($path)) {
      $route_name = $url->getRouteName();
      if (strpos($route_name, 'view.') === 0) {
        $view_route = $route_name;
      }
    }
    $view_routes[$path] = $view_route; 
  }

  return $view_routes;
}
```

[`PathValidator::getUrlIfValid()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Path%21PathValidator.php/function/PathValidator%3A%3AgetUrlIfValid/8.9.x) returns a `Url` object if the path it gets as argument is valid and accessible from the currently logged-in user. To understand which paths are for pages handled by the Views module, independently from which users have access to that page, the code should be similar to the following one.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\RequestMatcherInterface;

function _view_routes(array $paths) {
  $view_routes = [];
  $router = \Drupal::service('router.no_access_checks');

  foreach ($paths as $path) {
    try {
      $match = $router->match($path);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
      // The path isn't valid or the HTTP method to access the
      // path isn't allowed.
      $view_routes[$path] = '';
      continue;
    }

    $view_routes[$path] = (strpos($match['_route'], 'view.') === 0 ? $match['_route'] : '');
  }

  return $view_routes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @apaderno for your solution.